# OpenGTS with GoogleMaps V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, web, gps

I have managed to build OpenGTS 2.4.7 and works well. I would like to use GoogleMaps V3 instead, however i am not sure how to go about this.  I have read the google tutorials but not sure how to make the changes.

I would be very grateful if someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue by the use of Google API site and a few sites. So first of you have to create a GoogleMapsV3.js and edit the GoogleMaps.java file.

Rebuild the track files and reload.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to migrate OpenGTS v.2.4.7 from GoogleMapsAPIv2 to GoogleMapsAPIv3.
follow this link [sourceforge forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/opengts/discussion/579834/thread/9b9fa0d0/#bf41/b933/1266)

here is the GoogleMapsV3.js file [link to file](http://pastebin.com/8jwVhhK3)

My OpenGTS version is 2.4.7.
I were using GoogleMaps APIv2, today it was disabled by Google, so i made the following changes:

1. Placed above GoogleMapsV3.js file in %GTS_HOME%/war/track/js/maps/ directory.
2. Added property in the private.xml as follows:

   ```
   <MapProvider name="googleMaps"
     active="${Domain.MapProvider.active=true}"
     class="org.opengts.war.maps.jsmap.GoogleMaps"
     key="${Domain.MapProvider.key=<<my api key>>}"
     rtPropPrefix="Domain.MapProvider."&gt;

       <Property key="google.version">3</Property>
   ```

That's all, everything works fine now.
PS. The key from apiV2 also works for apiV3.

Here is the newer version of GoogleMapsV3.js:  pastebin.com/8jwVhhK3

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Can you please expland your answer, writing a short abstract from that link, so even if the link goes 404 in the future your answer will still be applicable?